# What is the best way to introduce OH group into aromatics directly?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, aromatic-compounds

I will try reactions to **hydroxylate a haloaryl compound containing fluorines and a NH group**. 
I consulted databases but could not find ways where yields are good.
If there are people good ways  to introduce a OH group into the compound directly, please tell me.

Comment: There is no universal and good direct methods, since electrophilic oxygen is not a nice thing to begin with and hard to come by.  The usual way to go around it is to utilized sequence of lithation (BuLi + ArH = BuH + ArLi) followed with synthesis of arylborate ester (ArLi + B(OMe)3 = ArB(OMe)2 + LiOMe) and than oxidation (ArB(OMe2) + H2O2 =  ArOH + HOB(OMe)2) in a basic solution).  Fluorine isn't a very mobile atom in transmetallation with organolithium compounds, so using extremely low temperature it might be possible to preserve it.